# $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt n]$ is isomorphic to the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, ring-isomorphism

To prove the above statement, I have defined the following map: $(a+b\sqrt n,c+d\sqrt n) \rightarrow (a+b\sqrt n)(c+d\sqrt n)^{-1}$ where $c+d\sqrt n    \ne0$ and $(c+d\sqrt n)^{-1} = \frac{c}{c^2-d^2n}-\frac{d}{c^2-d^2n}\sqrt n$

However, I'm stuck at showing that the above homomorphism is surjective.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re making it too complicated. Let $F = \operatorname{Quot} ℤ[\sqrt n]$ be the field of fractions of $ℤ[\sqrt n]$. Then clearly $F ⊆ ℚ(\sqrt n) = ℚ[\sqrt n]$ because $ℤ[\sqrt n] ⊆ ℚ(\sqrt n)$. But also $ℚ ⊆ F$ and $\sqrt n ∈ F$. Hence …

Comment: I think it is instructive to add that *any* algebraic number $\alpha$ could be used instead of $\sqrt{n}$ and the proof wouldn't change; in other words, $\sqrt{n}$ is a red herring.

Comment: Hidden in this answer is the fact that you are using the universal property definition of the field of fractions: $\mathrm{Quot}(R)$ is the smallest field containing $R$. The OP is using the constructive definition. This goes to show how thinking of things in terms of universal properties makes life significantly easier!

Comment: @Mathmo123 Yes, good point! I was thinking about adding a paragraph regarding this. I decided to only do this if so requested by the questioner in order to not clutter my answer.

Comment: just needed to clarify something. Firstly since Z[$\sqrt n$] is a subset of Q[$\sqrt n$](which is a field), the the field of fractions of Z[$\sqrt n$] would be isomorphic to a subfield of Q[$\sqrt n$](through ((a,b)$\rightarrow ab^{-1}$)). But to show that this subfield is Q[$\sqrt n$] itself, isn't that equivalent to showing subjectivity? I still can't seem to see how that is the case.

Comment: btw would the following work to show surjectivity for the specific case above: $(r_1r_4+r_3r_2 \sqrt n, r_2r_4)$ $\rightarrow$  $\frac{r_1}{r_2} + \frac{r_3}{r_4}\sqrt n $

Comment: @JhonDoe Yes, it would.